# Handle leak in std::thread c++

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++, handle

today I noticed a strange think when using std::thread. This is minimal test case:

```
void test() 
{
    std::thread t1([] {}); 
    t1.join();
}
```

Every time I run this code, one Handle leaked.

This is a view from ProcessExplorer. These leaked handles are thread mutexes "BaseNammedObjects\bx_thread_mutex"

[image]

These mutexes are not released anytime future. Is this some know issue?

I'm using latest Visual Studio 2019 16.7.3 and I'm testing it on 32bit app (debug and release too).

**Edited:**

Leaked handles are liner to number of execution, so this snippet:

```
for (int n = 0; n < 1000; n++)
{
    std::thread t1([] {});
    t1.join();
}
```

creates 1000 leaked handles: [image]

Comment: how do you build the code? debug or release?

Comment: I tried both with the same results.

Comment: Does the number of these things scale in proportion to the number of threads? Like does 1,000 threads result in N*1000 of these things? I'm curious if they aren't some kind of pool used by the `std::thread` subsystem and are recycled, but will not go below a particular count to keep some in reserve.

Comment: And what is strange, I tried it with boost::thread instead of std::thread and the behavior is exactly the same.

Comment: @tadman it's a linear. When I loop it over 1000 times then 1000 new leaks appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the semi-false alarm.

The issue seems to be caused by 3rd party plugin Deleaker (I'm just testing now) used for memory leak detection (funny, right? ;-) ).

When I disable this plugin, everything works ok. So it's something that Deleaker does inside. I will report this issue to the author.

**Edit:** It seems that the latest version of Deleaker fixes this issue.

[image]

Comment: @TanveerBadar not yet ;-) "You can accept your own answer in 15 hours"